# Combo box birt to excel

Tags: xml, birt

I need to create a drop-down list or combo in eclipse in a birt report to later export to Excel and the drop-down combo is shown, it was tried with `xml` tags, but it doesn't work, it was tried with `html` tags and when generating the birt it shows the drop-down combo but at the same time exporting to excel does not show it, I attach an image of the drop-down combo that I need, I appreciate the help provided.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

BIRT can generate nice Excel file with a lot of formatting, images etc, but this is not possible with BIRT AFAIK.

You should consider using a different tool for this special kind of task,
or maybe the commercial software from OpenText.

What you could try with BIRT (but this more or less undocumented and requires intimate knowledge of BIRT and good Excel knowledge, so I don't recommend it):

AFAIK the Spudsoft Excel emitter (included in BIRT) supports an Excel template file. That is, you can load an existing XLSX file and modify one of the sheets. That way you could change the elements in the existing drop-down listbox.

I tink few programs except Excel itself can generate highly interactive Excel files.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I will try as indicated